# installing oracle-xe does not work as expected

Tags: dpkg, oracle

```
mahdi@mahdidell:~/Downloads/Disk1$ sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 196287 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking oracle-xe (11.2.0-2) ...
dpkg-deb: error: unexpected end of file in archive member header in oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.32-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: You didn't include the complete error message, you didn't use the formatting tools to make your question readable, and you asked, in French (with English error messages) on an English site.  It's hard to help you, but "`unexpected end of file in archive member header in oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb`" ("`fin inattendue du fichier dans l'en-tête du membre de l'archive dans oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb`" suggests a bad download of `oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb`.

Comment: i'm sorry @waltinator i speak french more than english and thank you to help me . and this is my first experience ask ubuntu .